# How to remove first set of numbers from column names?

Tags: r, gsub

I have column names, for example they look like this `20819830_r1ar_u_stationary` and `2081974_f8ar_u`. I am trying to get rid of the first set of numbers in the column names. I tried using this code

```
names(df)[1:2] <- gsub("^.*_","",names(df[,c(1:2)]))
```

but when I use this, the column names turn to `stationary` and `u`. I can see the code is removing everything up until the last `_`  how do I change the code so that it removes everything up until the first `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching `.*` - one or more characters as `.` matches any characters, it should be one or more digits (`\\d+`) from the start (`^`) of the string

```
names(df)[1:2] <- sub("^\\d+_", "", names(df)[1:2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `stringr`. `str_remove` will remove the first set of digits that are followed by an underscore:

```
library(stringr)
str="20819830_r1ar_u_stationary"
str_remove(str, "^[0-9]+(?=_)_")
```

```
[1] "r1ar_u_stationary"
```